# Javascript Forms Calculator with No answers

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator

I am very new to really writing javascript (borrowing and editing, not so new).  So with a little help from google and code guru and adobe cookbook, I have come up with this simple form to be embedded into an iPad publication (this is just my test, not the final product).  I have gotten it this far with no errors if the debug console and it seems to pass W3C compliance, but it also doesn't do anything!  It doesn't generate the answers???  I am hoping someone can help me out or steer me in the right direction. the code for the page is below:  Thanks in advance...

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item</th>
  <th scope="col">Cost 1</th>
  <th scope="col">Cost 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Manikin</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="ManikinCost1" id="ManikinCost1" tabindex="1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ManikinCost2" id="ManikinCost2" tabindex="2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Instructor</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="InstructorCost1" id="InstructorCost1" tabindex="3" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="InstructorCost2" id="InstructorCost2" tabindex="4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Books</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="BooksCost1" id="BooksCost1" tabindex="5" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BooksCost2" id="BooksCost2" tabindex="6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Totals</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="TotalsCost1" id="TotalsCost1" tabindex="7" /><span id="TotalsCost1"></span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TotalsCost2" id="TotalsCost2" tabindex="8" /><span id="TotalsCost2"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Savings</th>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="Savings" id="Savings" /><span id="Savings"></span></td>
</tr>
      </table>
      <p>
        <input type="button" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('calculate');
    btn.onclick = function() {
//get the input values
var ManikinCost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ManikinCost1').value);
var ManikinCost2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ManikinCost2').value);
var InstructorCost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('InstructorCost1').value);
var InstructorCost2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('InstructorCost2').value);
var BooksCost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('BooksCost1').value);
var BooksCost2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('BooksCost2').value);
// get the elements to hold the results
var TotalsCost1 = document.getElementById('TotalsCost1');
var TotalsCost2 = document.getElementById('TotalsCost2');
var Savings = document.getElementById('Savings');
// create an empty array to hold error messages
var msg = [];
// check each input value, and add an error message to the array if it's not a number
if (isNaN(ManikinCost2)) {
    msg.push('Manikin Cost 2 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(InstructorCost1)) {
    msg.push('Instructor Cost 1 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
        }
if (isNaN(InstructorCost2)) {
    msg.push('Instructor Cost 2 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(BooksCost1)) {
    msg.push('Book Cost 1 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(ManikinCost1)) {
    msg.push('Manikin Cost 1 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(BooksCost2)) {
    msg.push('Book Cost 2 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
    // if the array contains any values, display an error message
    if (msg.length > 0)   {
        TotalsCost1.innerHTML = msg.join(', ');
    } else {
        TotalsCost1.innerHTML = + (ManikinCost1 + InstructorCost1 + BooksCost1);
        TotalsCost2.innerHTML = + (ManikinCost2 + InstructorCost2 + BooksCost2);
        Savings.innerHTML = + (TotalsCost1 - TotalsCost2);
    }
    };
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.onclick = (function(){...})();
```

You need to put `onclick` events inside self-calling code, or what are called closures. Move your entire `btn.onclick` function inside of this bit of code: `(...)()` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Good attempt, a few small things wrong but pretty close!

I have made a few changes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GaryHarrower/8HgA6/3/).

As mentioned in a comment, I wrapped the function with brackets (function() {...});

I also changed innerHTML to be value as we are updating text inputs, and your savings calculation should be input.value, which I have updated for you.

Let me know how you get on!

```
   <body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item</th>
  <th scope="col">Cost 1</th>
  <th scope="col">Cost 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Manikin</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="ManikinCost1" id="ManikinCost1" tabindex="1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ManikinCost2" id="ManikinCost2" tabindex="2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Instructor</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="InstructorCost1" id="InstructorCost1" tabindex="3" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="InstructorCost2" id="InstructorCost2" tabindex="4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Books</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="BooksCost1" id="BooksCost1" tabindex="5" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BooksCost2" id="BooksCost2" tabindex="6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Totals</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="TotalsCost1" id="TotalsCost1" tabindex="7" /><span id="TotalsCost1"></span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TotalsCost2" id="TotalsCost2" tabindex="8" /><span id="TotalsCost2"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Savings</th>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="Savings" id="Savings" /><span id="Savings"></span></td>
</tr>
      </table>
      <p>
        <input type="button" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById('calculate');
    btn.onclick = (function() {
//get the input values
var ManikinCost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ManikinCost1').value);
var ManikinCost2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ManikinCost2').value);
var InstructorCost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('InstructorCost1').value);
var InstructorCost2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('InstructorCost2').value);
var BooksCost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('BooksCost1').value);
var BooksCost2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('BooksCost2').value);
// get the elements to hold the results
var TotalsCost1 = document.getElementById('TotalsCost1');
var TotalsCost2 = document.getElementById('TotalsCost2');
var Savings = document.getElementById('Savings');
// create an empty array to hold error messages
var msg = [];
// check each input value, and add an error message to the array if it's not a number
if (isNaN(ManikinCost2)) {
    msg.push('Manikin Cost 2 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(InstructorCost1)) {
    msg.push('Instructor Cost 1 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
        }
if (isNaN(InstructorCost2)) {
    msg.push('Instructor Cost 2 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(BooksCost1)) {
    msg.push('Book Cost 1 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(ManikinCost1)) {
    msg.push('Manikin Cost 1 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
if (isNaN(BooksCost2)) {
    msg.push('Book Cost 2 is not a number');
    // the value isn't a number
    }
    // if the array contains any values, display an error message
    if (msg.length > 0)   {
        TotalsCost1.innerHTML = msg.join(', ');
    } else {

        TotalsCost1.value = + (ManikinCost1 + InstructorCost1 + BooksCost1);
        TotalsCost2.value = + (ManikinCost2 + InstructorCost2 + BooksCost2);
        Savings.value = + (TotalsCost1.value - TotalsCost2.value);
    }
    });

    </script>
    </body>
```